# Are the phrases 'into the bargain' and to boot' synonymous with 'as well'?

Tags: phrase-usage

Here's the sentence that I don't understand taken from English Vocabulary In Use:

> He was a good sportsman and an excellent musician **into the
> bargain/to boot**. [emphasises the combination of items; *infml*]

I don't know what that means by emphasising the combination of items. Is it just the same way when we say **as well** or **too**? Something that we would say after adding the last information to some things we have just said?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It generally means something like "as well", usually (as in your example) for things that aren't particularly associated. That is especially true of "to boot".

There is no reason that sportsmanship and musicianship need appear in single individuals, they can both be true, both be false or be present in either combination without the other.

The sentence is emphasizing that the subject has multiple admirable qualities (assuming, of course, that you find sportsmanship and musical ability positive qualities).